# Casesensitive vs. Caseinsensitive Collatesequences?

Tags: sqlite, collation, case-sensitive

I just started working with the SQLite database places.sqlite.

Fact is that this database uses case sensitive collate sequences making writing queries as funny as in Oracle.

I want to know, are there really any applications where the user wants case sensitive sorting.

Or is the default use of case sensitive sorting a heritage of the fact that binary sort order is cheaper than the other forms.

**EDIT:**

Just in case you are curious. SQLite can handle caseinsenitive compares. [see this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/973541/how-to-set-sqlite3-to-be-case-insensitive-when-string-comparing)

BTW what is the state of art with Oracle. We migrated our SQL databases to ORACLE at the time of 8i and never checked, if we can do it caseinsensitive today.

Answer (score 1):

In oracle it is possible since 10.2. Take a look here [Case-Insensitive and Accent-Insensitive Linguistic Sorts](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch5lingsort.htm#i1009059),so you might want to take a look again, 8i is a while ago now ....